# Robot methods has no effects inside a game

Tags: java

I'm trying to make a bot using Java Robot methods but it has no effects inside the game.
The game is using xtrap as a shield, is there any way to bypass it?

Here is a code example:

```
try {
        Robot r = new Robot();
        r.delay(1000);
        r.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
        r.delay(1000);
        r.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
        r.delay(1000);
    }
```

Comment: Post an example that we can use to reproduce your problem.

Comment: @DelmerNicholson Posted.

Comment: Are you calling `r.mouseMove()` to position the robot cursor where you want the click event to occur?

Comment: @NathanielJones I just place it manually, I also tried to execute a KeyPress method and it had no effect. I created many bot programs already I know how to use the class, in this game the xtrap is blocking it. I read somewhere that I have to communicate directly with the driver but I don't know if that's possible with java..